# Trying to search for a certain pattern in text file

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pattern-matching

Okay so in Python, I'm trying to search for the pattern "comma, space, any lowercase character", but I cant get a regular expression that seems to work. The whole regular expressions thing is pretty new to me and I have no idea what I'm doing. I was able to search for a "number, space, any character using "[1-9]+ [a-zA-z]", but I'm not sure how to search for the pattern mentioned above. The picture included is an example of what pattern I am trying to search for in the text file.

Thanks,
Schulzy

[image: picture of text file]

Comment: `r',\s+[a-z]+'`

Comment: regex101.com is a great site to experiment on different regexes, and learn some of the special features by using the in-page docs.

Comment: @Schulzy Welcome to SO! Please share text [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Among other things, it's a real pain for anyone who wants to actually type all that up to test their proposed solution. As a result, you may get less accurate answers and fewer of them. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that this is my first ever post. Thank you for the pointer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Regex expression that would work is
`, [a-z]`
the comma and space are matched exactly, and the '[]' is a group, where anything in the group could be matched. you want any lowercase char's, so we put `[a-z]` for any character between lowercase a to z.